# Replacing index in an expression

Tags: replacement

I have an expression:

```
Test =Subscript[t, 2, i] Subscript[x, 1, i];
```

I want to replace i to j. Is there a way?

Comment: Never name a variable starting with upper-case letter as it can conflict with internal function names.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Did you mean Test?

Comment: As I wrote, you should *never* name a variable starting with an upper-case letter.  In short, use `test`, never `Test`.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sure

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is:

```
test /. i -> j
```